# Error with GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the error:

```
Column 'dbo.Saved_ORDER_IMPORT.Company' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

When i execute :

```
SELECT [Order No], Company
FROM [dbo].[Saved_ORDER_IMPORT] 
where [sent] = 1 and datesent  between '01/01/2009' and '01/27/2012'
group by [Order No]
```

do i have to change the column or my query?

Comment: What are you trying to do?   If you are trying to sort by order #, then company, change the group by to ORDER BY.   If you are trying to roll things up, give us more detail and you'll get some help...

Comment: Yes, please describe what you are trying to achieve.  So that we can both identify the issue, and also explain how to correct it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Description**:

You can't group your query by only one column because you select 2.

> **MSDN** - Groups a selected set of rows into a set of summary rows by the values of one or more columns or expressions in SQL Server. One row is returned for each group. Aggregate functions in the SELECT clause  list provide information about each group instead of individual rows.

We need more information but maybe this helps

**Sample**:

```
SELECT [Order No], Company
FROM [dbo].[Saved_ORDER_IMPORT] 
WHERE [sent] = 1 AND datesent BETWEEN '01/01/2009' AND '01/27/2012'
GROUP BY [Order No], Company
```

More information:

- [MSDN - GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You must put the Company field in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY clause tells SQL to return 1 row for each item in the group by list.  In your case, you want one row per order number.   If want company too, you need to include it in the group by.

By if all you want is a sorted by order #, company, remove the group by and use ORDER BY instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove company from the select or group by company, too.

To give you an example:

You have five order numbers and two companies
1 - Company1
1 - Company2
2 - Company1
2 - Company2
3 - Company1

Now you group by order number, so you have 3 results:
1
2
3

... but what's the company for the order number results? Because order number 1 can either bei Company1 or Company2.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning that error because you are not using an [AGGREGATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) function in your select statement.  Including the [Company] field in the GROUP BY statement would remove the error but it would not make sense.